Duplicated TopAppBar when implementing the new SplashScreen APIs in Android
I just implemented the new splash screen APIs on my app and everything works as expected, except for one thing! A new topAppBar showed up on top of my old one, which I'm implementing using jetpack Compose.
Illustration

My approach

The theme.xml file:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="Theme.RememberMe" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar" />

    <style name="Theme.App.SplashScreen" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
        <item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">#396846</item>
        <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/Theme.RememberMe</item>
        <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground</item>
    </style>
</resources>


The AndroidManifest.xml file

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />

    <application
       ...
        android:theme="@style/Theme.App.SplashScreen"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
           ...
        </activity>

    </application>
    ...
</manifest>


In my MainActivity.kt file, I used the installSplashScreen() method in onCreate() method

 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        installSplashScreen()

        setContent {
            RememberMeApp()
        }


As I said, the splash screen works just fine, but the problem with this duplicated TopAppBar

Add one more item <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item> in SplashScreen style in theme.xml file.

@PremDanej it didn't work

Did you find any solution for this?

I was also facing similar issue, having installSplashScreen() before enableEdgeToEdge() solves the issue.
